# jsdoc @callback operator in webstorm

Tags: webstorm, jsdoc3

I think I'm doing it the way it's explained in jsdoc3 documentation.
My WebStorm is version 8.0.4

```
/**
 * This callback type is called `dbOpenCallback` and is displayed as a global symbol.
 *
 * @callback dbOpenCallback
 * @param {object} err
 * @param {DbWrapper} result
*/

/**
 * Open mongodb connection
 * @param {dbOpenCallback} cb - The callback that executes after connection is established.
*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@callback is not supported in WebStorm 8.0.4. [WEB-12803](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12803) is fixed in webStorm 9, please try the [EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+9+EAP) to see if it works for you